# Footnote Horizontal Line

Tags: footnotes, rules

I am using a the [IOP](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument) (Institute of Physics) LaTeX class/templates, I am trying to add a footnote but it is not showing a horizontal line. Is there a way to force this or define a new rule to make sure one is appearing? Here is a simple example of what I am doing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,helvetica,a4paper,final]{iopart}
\usepackage{iopams} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\title[Short Title]{Short Title: Subtitle}
\author{H. A.}
\section{Introduction}
Here I have an introduction \footnote{check out this note also!}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document class `iopart.cls` has

```
304: \def\footnoterule{}%
```

which removes the footnote rule. You can grab the definition from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

```
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high
\makeatother
```

Peace has been restored:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,helvetica,a4paper,final]{iopart}

\usepackage{iopams}

\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high
\makeatother

\title[Short Title]{Short Title: Subtitle}
\author{Husni Almoubayyed}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here I have an introduction \footnote{check out this note also!}.

\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- For journal submissions I'd avoid such changes.
- Based on *any* template you should set `\title` and friends *before* executing `\maketitle`.